# Use custom OpenCV install in ROS package

Tags: cmake, opencv3.0, ros, catkin

I am trying to build a ROS package in which I use a custom OpenCV 3.4 install in which I have CUDA enabled. The OpenCV install, in /usr/local, is working just fine, I can build and run samples from the GPU folder no problem using

```
g++ -o houghlines houghlines.cpp `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`
```

However, I just cannot get catkin to use my install of OpenCV, rather than the one that ships with ROS. Here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(motion_segmentation_cuda)

set(CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER  /usr/local/cuda-9.1/bin/nvcc)
find_package(catkin_simple REQUIRED)

set(OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS
  /usr/local/include
  /usr/local/include/opencv2
)
set(OpenCV_LIB_DIR
  /usr/local/lib
)
set(OpenCV_LIBS
  opencv_core
  opencv_highgui
  opencv_imgcodecs
)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)
catkin_simple()

#Here you can set any gcc/cmake compiler flags, if you so wish
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -O3")
link_directories(${OpenCV_LIB_DIR})

#Add all of your sources here
cuda_add_executable(
  cuda_test_cu
  src/main.cpp
  src/motion_segmenter.cpp
  src/kernel.cu
  src/segmenter.cpp
)

#Link the executable to the necessary libs
target_link_libraries(
   cuda_test_cu
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
   ${OpenCV_LIBS}
   ${CUDA_LIBRARIES}
)

# CMake Indexing
FILE(GLOB_RECURSE LibFiles "include/*")
add_custom_target(headers SOURCES ${LibFiles})

cs_install()
```

On the advice of various forums I have also tried to

```
export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/usr/lib/:$CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

And a whole myriad of tweaks in the CMakeLists. And my package compiles just fine! But in the end, I inevitably get:

```
OpenCV Error: No CUDA support (The library is compiled without CUDA support) in throw_no_cuda, file /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.3.1/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/private.cuda.hpp, line 107
```

As soon as I try to actually use any of the GPU enabled OpenCV classes.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, past me, this CMakeLists.txt works (for some reason):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(motion_segmentation_cuda)

find_package(OpenCV 3.4 REQUIRED
  COMPONENTS
    opencv_core
    opencv_highgui
    opencv_imgproc
    opencv_imgcodecs
  PATHS /usr/local
  NO_DEFAULT_PATH
  CONFIG
)

set(CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER  /usr/local/cuda-9.1/bin/nvcc)
find_package(catkin_simple REQUIRED)
find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)
catkin_simple()

#Here you can set any gcc/cmake compiler flags, if you so wish
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -O3")

include_directories(include ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

#Add all of your sources here
cuda_add_executable(
  cuda_test_cu
  src/main.cpp
  src/motion_segmenter.cpp
  src/kernel.cu
  src/segmenter.cpp
)

#Link the executable to the necessary libs
target_link_libraries(
   cuda_test_cu
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
   ${OpenCV_LIBS}
   ${CUDA_LIBRARIES}
)

# CMake Indexing
FILE(GLOB_RECURSE LibFiles "include/*")
add_custom_target(headers SOURCES ${LibFiles})

cs_install()
```

No need to change the `.bashrc` in the end...